# Android get an int for Android cursor.getCount()

Tags: android

I got a problem with a function in my android projet.
I want to know if a row in my database exists. I did :

```
public Cursor selectMagasinByName(String name)
{
    return mDb.rawQuery("select numMagasin as _id, nomMagasin, adresse from magasin where nomMagasin = ?", new String[]{name});
}

public boolean verifDoublonMagasinByName(String name)
{
    Cursor cursor = selectMagasinByName(name);
    int rows = (int) cursor.getCount();
    if (rows < 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Each time this function returns false, even if I add an 'else if' condition which tests if `rows == 0`

Comment: try replacing your `if` as `if (rows < =0)`.

Comment: Oh great.. :).. I've added that as my answer @Samael.. Please accept the answer if that really helped you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be `cursor.getCount()` returns `0` and thats why the `if` is not being executed.

Replace

```
if (rows < 0)
```

with

```
 if (rows <= 0)
```

And, according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount()), by default , the `getCount ()` returns an `int`, you dont have to actually explicitly type cast that to `int`.